# Empty child div with a background image to take up 100% of parent div height

Tags: html, css

Found it as not that easy task to force the child div to take the full height of its background image.
There are six obligatory terms:

1. Exact height is unknown for both div
2. Child div is empty
3. Background image size: `cover`
4. `display: flex`
5. No javascript
6. It's a list's item (thus no fullscreen)

```css
.item { 
  display: flex; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  height: 100%; 
}
.inner { 
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504608524841-42fe6f032b4b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80') center center / cover no-repeat; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  Inner content
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

All similar questions found on SO don't pass all or some of terms.
Would be grateful for any thoughts (especially from `grid` gurus).

Comment: use `height: 100vh` for `item`?

Comment: Sixth term: no fullscreens :)

Comment: whant you want then is not a background-image but an image

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry, rule #2

Comment: which confirms that you want an image ;) since it's empty then you can put the image inside and the image will define the height

Comment: more important is to explain what you want to achieve instead of listing a set of *impossible* requirements. You are probably tackling this the wrong way.

Comment: In my case there are restrictions that cause Rule #2. Otherwise I would solve it by myself.

Comment: What is the height of the parent supposed to be? You have an empty child inside an empty parent now. (Well, the parent is technically not empty, but there's no substantial content.)

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's a list of items with images of unknown height (from 5px to 1500px)

Comment: @MrLister might be of any height, but not exact in px, em, rem, vh (Rule #1)

Comment: @TemaniAfif if it's impossible, then make it as an answer

Comment: Your example would be clearer if you put some content in the outer div (giving it some intrinsic height), and explaining where the inner div should be placed compared to the content. Also, the question in the title is not the same as the question in the body.

Comment: I don't make it as anwser since I don't know the initial goal. What you listed here is *impossible* but if you give us more details we can think about different alternatives but it's clear that you cannot adjust height of element based on it's background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the image determine the height of the inner div (as if it were an <img> element), use this.

```css
.item { 
  display: flex; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  height: 100%; 
}

.inner { 
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inner::before {
  font-size:0;
  content: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504608524841-42fe6f032b4b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80');
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Note that this answers the question in the first sentence of the question body, which is not the same as the question in the title.

Comment: @Igniter you see, it's an image at the end ;) and there is no background and no `cover` rule

Comment: @Igniter yes it's still impossible .. in this solution (which is the logical solution) the child isn't empty (no rule #2) and no background-size:cover (no rule #3) ... so why not simply adding the image in the HTML which is a lot easier that using CSS to include the image?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You must understand that there are many situations where the most logical solution just isn't possible. Suppose the HTML can't be changed, and JavaScript is impossible. Some CMSes have those restrictions! Then the only way out is to try CSS.

Comment: @MrLister I totally understand this and that's why those details need to belong to the question. The OP said *I want to use background-image and I need the parent element to consider its height* --> we both know that it's impossible. But if the OP said *I want to add images but I am not able to change the HTML* then it's a different story and we can find a lot of workarounds (your solution confirm this), That's why I am asking what is the goal behind this ;)